# Android: Boot Complete only works if I launch App Immediately

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, startup

I'm trying to reset alarms in my app and using a receiver to get onBootCompleted. To see if the intent was received, I'm using a toast. The toast only appears if I immediately open the app. Otherwise, the toast does not appear. I looked at previous questions but almost all of them involve services, which I am not using. I am not sure if that is a part of the problem.

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
package="package.name" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALARM_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReset"android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Receiver Class

```
public class AlarmReset extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Toast.makeText(context, "Hello! Got message",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//reset alarms etc. No service set.
}
```

I also tried writing the manifest receiver as

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReset" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Key points I found online were to include permissions (which I did) and to watch out for logging.

What I do not understand is why it works if I immediately (within a few seconds, otherwise the toast does not appear) start my activity but is unsuccessful otherwise. I am considering testing a few possibilities like launching the activity itself through code or using a service like most others have. I am currently testing on Android 4.4 on an actual phone.

Comment: You have to use services.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'll do that

Comment: Btw, @CodeProcessor Do you think you could mention why or redirect me to someplace that explains it? I'll read the developer API for services but I would like to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Android 3.1 all applications, upon installation, are placed in a "stopped" state.(This is the same state that the application ends up in after the user force-stops the app from the Settings application.)

While in "stopped" state, the application will not run for any reason, except by a manual launch of an activity. (Meaning no BroadcastReceviers(ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALLED, BOOT_COMPLETED etc.) will be invoked, regardless of the event for which they have registered, until the user runs the app manually.)

But you can start a serivice for ex-

1) In your  element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

2) In your  element (be sure to use a fully-qualified [or relative] class name for your BroadcastReceiver):

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

In MyBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
package com.example;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the app is never moved out of the stopped state, how does `MyBroadcastReceiver` start receiving the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast?

Comment: Please consider answering the above question asked by @Karakuri

Answer (score 3):

When an app is installed, it is in a stopped state. None of its components will be activated (such as your `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver) until the app is moved out of this state by being launched by the user. This is why your app doesn't work unless you launch it once.

Note that force stopping the app from Settings also moves it into this stopped state.

See [this page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html) for more details (search the page for "launch controls").

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but that is not the issue. I've read about this issue and moved to avoid it. The issue is probably? not using a service (I don't understand why but I think starting a service may work. I'm running some tests right now). So thanks anyway!

Comment: With respect, the answer you accepted is the same as mine. His sample `BroadcastReceiver` may be starting a `Service`, but the app still must be launched at least once for the receiver to start receiving the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. Nothing about starting a service changes that.

Comment: Yeah I think so too. The important part was that he mentioned to start a service. In all honestly, the answer may have as well been his comment (which was probably the most useful, since I was not sure if I needed to or not). The actual explanation is something I'll look for myself. I think the issue was that I was trying to launch AlarmManager in the BroadCastReceiver class. I moved the code to the service class and it worked. Unfortunately, I'm still a novice at Android Programming, and programming in general, so I may have missed the obvious. Again, thanks so much for trying to help.

Comment: I am very sorry for the vagueness and I really appreciate your attempt to help. I'll post my own solution to help clear things and hopefully help someone in the future, though the situation may be a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the need to clarify the issue and solution, since the question was not clear (due to confidentiality issues).

The Basic Solution to my problem was just starting a service.

The Problem: I was trying to make the alarm in my class, AlarmReset, through AlarmManager. That in itself may have been an issue, but in addition, I tried to access objects that were instantiated in the MainActivity, furthering my dilemma. The reason why it worked when I opened MainActivity quickly enough, I suspect, is because I was able to instantiate the objects and set up the prerequisites for the class to directly access. I think the toast not appearing is similar to the issue.

The Solution: I set up a service class which I directed AlarmReset to. This is what I changed the AlarmReset class to:

```
public class AlarmReset extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Toast.makeText(context, "Hello! Got message",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//Pretty sure the Toast doesn't appear still. 
    Intent service = new Intent(context, Service.class);
    context.startService(service);
}
```

Then my service class

```
public class Service extends IntentService {
private DataBaseManager database;

public Service()
{
    super("Service");
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    database = new DataBaseManager(this);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hi",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Hello! Got message",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//rest of code
}
```

Similarly, the text does not appear except if I am on the app immediately (I suspect it has to do with the threads).

Here, I made sure to instantiate my objects before using them (or did so after crashing).

A few possible problems that others may encounter (as I have read) are the following:
Installing in internal storage

- `android:installLocation="internalOnly"`

and receiving permission for booting

- `<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Some problems that people had suggested and were not very important were:

- Using android:enabled and android:exported. Default values are fine
- Writing the full receiver name. For me it wasn't necessary
- `<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />` did not seem to do much.